# How do I get Qlistview to include all the search details for pdf hits in QPdfSearchModel Class for python like it does in the documentation

Tags: python, pdf, qlistview, qabstractitemmodel, qpdf

When I do a pdf search using the QPdfsearchmodel class my model only seems to include the word I searched for and context before/context after:

[image]

However, in the documentation there is also a listing for the page no.:

[image: From QPdfSearchModel Class documentation]

I modified the Pyside6 port of the pdfwidgets/pdfviewer example from Qt v6.x by adding a text search bar to the top and replacing the bookmark view pane on the left with a Qlistview for the search results:

[https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_pdfwidgets_pdfviewer.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have tried everything I can think of. I only modified mainwindow.py and ui_mainwindow.py below:

## Copyright (C) 2022 The Qt Company Ltd.

## SPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-Qt-Commercial OR BSD-3-Clause

```
import math
import sys

from PySide6.QtPdf import QPdfBookmarkModel, QPdfDocument,QPdfSearchModel
from PySide6.QtPdfWidgets import QPdfView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QFileDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox,
                               QSpinBox,QLineEdit)
from PySide6.QtCore import QModelIndex, QPoint, QStandardPaths, QUrl, Slot

from zoomselector import ZoomSelector
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow


ZOOM_MULTIPLIER = math.sqrt(2.0)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.m_zoomSelector = ZoomSelector(self)
        self.m_pageSelector = QSpinBox(self)
        self.m_document = QPdfDocument(self)
        self.m_fileDialog = None
        self.m_search = QLineEdit(self)
        self.m_searchModel=QPdfSearchModel(self)

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.m_zoomSelector.setMaximumWidth(150)
        self.ui.mainToolBar.insertWidget(self.ui.actionZoom_In, self.m_zoomSelector)

        self.ui.mainToolBar.insertWidget(self.ui.actionForward, self.m_pageSelector)
        self.m_pageSelector.valueChanged.connect(self.page_selected)
        
        #Add SearchBar
        self.ui.mainToolBar.addWidget(self.m_search)
        
        nav = self.ui.pdfView.pageNavigator()
        nav.currentPageChanged.connect(self.m_pageSelector.setValue)
        nav.backAvailableChanged.connect(self.ui.actionBack.setEnabled)
        nav.forwardAvailableChanged.connect(self.ui.actionForward.setEnabled)

        #Add model to searchView
        self.ui.searchView.setModel(self.m_searchModel)
        
        #Set SeletctionModel
        self.selModel=self.ui.searchView.selectionModel()
        
        self.m_zoomSelector.zoom_mode_changed.connect(self.ui.pdfView.setZoomMode)
        self.m_zoomSelector.zoom_factor_changed.connect(self.ui.pdfView.setZoomFactor)
        self.m_zoomSelector.reset()
        self.m_search.textChanged.connect(self.searchChange)
        self.selModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.selChange)
        



        


        self.ui.pdfView.setDocument(self.m_document)

        self.ui.pdfView.zoomFactorChanged.connect(self.m_zoomSelector.set_zoom_factor)
        
        # #add wordwrap
        self.ui.searchView.setWordWrap(True)

    
          
    def searchChange(self):
        
        #Set Search String
        self.m_searchModel.setSearchString(self.m_search.text())
        print(self.m_searchModel.searchString())
        
        #Set Document for Search
        self.m_searchModel.setDocument(self.m_document)
       

        
        print('==============')
        
    def selChange(self,index):
        print('click')
        item=self.selModel.selection().indexes()[0]
        print(item.data())

        
    
    
    
    
    
    @Slot(QUrl)
    def open(self, doc_location):
        if doc_location.isLocalFile():
            self.m_document.load(doc_location.toLocalFile())
            document_title = self.m_document.metaData(QPdfDocument.MetaDataField.Title)
            self.setWindowTitle(document_title if document_title else "PDF Viewer")
            self.page_selected(0)
            self.m_pageSelector.setMaximum(self.m_document.pageCount() - 1)
        else:
            message = f"{doc_location} is not a valid local file"
            print(message, file=sys.stderr)
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Failed to open", message)

    @Slot(QModelIndex)
    def bookmark_selected(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        page = index.data(int(QPdfBookmarkModel.Role.Page))
        zoom_level = index.data(int(QPdfBookmarkModel.Role.Level))
        self.ui.pdfView.pageNavigator().jump(page, QPoint(), zoom_level)

    @Slot(int)
    def page_selected(self, page):
        nav = self.ui.pdfView.pageNavigator()
        nav.jump(page, QPoint(), nav.currentZoom())

    @Slot()
    def on_actionOpen_triggered(self):
        if not self.m_fileDialog:
            directory = QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.DocumentsLocation)
            self.m_fileDialog = QFileDialog(self, "Choose a PDF", directory)
            self.m_fileDialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)
            self.m_fileDialog.setMimeTypeFilters(["application/pdf"])
        if self.m_fileDialog.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
            to_open = self.m_fileDialog.selectedUrls()[0]
            if to_open.isValid():
                self.open(to_open)

    @Slot()
    def on_actionQuit_triggered(self):
        self.close()

    @Slot()
    def on_actionAbout_triggered(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "About PdfViewer",
                          "An example using QPdfDocument")

    @Slot()
    def on_actionAbout_Qt_triggered(self):
        QMessageBox.aboutQt(self)

    @Slot()
    def on_actionZoom_In_triggered(self):
        factor = self.ui.pdfView.zoomFactor() * ZOOM_MULTIPLIER
        self.ui.pdfView.setZoomFactor(factor)

    @Slot()
    def on_actionZoom_Out_triggered(self):
        factor = self.ui.pdfView.zoomFactor() / ZOOM_MULTIPLIER
        self.ui.pdfView.setZoomFactor(factor)

    @Slot()
    def on_actionPrevious_Page_triggered(self):
        nav = self.ui.pdfView.pageNavigator()
        nav.jump(nav.currentPage() - 1, QPoint(), nav.currentZoom())

    @Slot()
    def on_actionNext_Page_triggered(self):
        nav = self.ui.pdfView.pageNavigator()
        nav.jump(nav.currentPage() + 1, QPoint(), nav.currentZoom())

    @Slot()
    def on_actionContinuous_triggered(self):
        cont_checked = self.ui.actionContinuous.isChecked()
        mode = QPdfView.PageMode.MultiPage if cont_checked else QPdfView.PageMode.SinglePage
        self.ui.pdfView.setPageMode(mode)

    @Slot()
    def on_actionBack_triggered(self):
        self.ui.pdfView.pageNavigator().back()

    @Slot()
    def on_actionForward_triggered(self):
        self.ui.pdfView.pageNavigator().forward()
```

And ui_mainwindow.py:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QAction, QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient,
    QCursor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient,
    QIcon, QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient,
    QPainter, QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient,
    QTransform)
from PySide6.QtPdfWidgets import QPdfView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHeaderView, QMainWindow, QMenu,
    QMenuBar, QSizePolicy, QSplitter, QStatusBar,
    QTabWidget, QToolBar, QTreeView, QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,QListView)
import resources_rc

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 600)
        MainWindow.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(True)
        self.actionOpen = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName(u"actionOpen")
        icon = QIcon()
        iconThemeName = u"document-open"
        if QIcon.hasThemeIcon(iconThemeName):
            icon = QIcon.fromTheme(iconThemeName)
        else:
            icon.addFile(u":/icons/images/document-open.svgz", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)

        self.actionOpen.setIcon(icon)
        self.actionQuit = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionQuit.setObjectName(u"actionQuit")
        icon1 = QIcon(QIcon.fromTheme(u"application-exit"))
        self.actionQuit.setIcon(icon1)
        self.actionAbout = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout.setObjectName(u"actionAbout")
        icon2 = QIcon(QIcon.fromTheme(u"help-about"))
        self.actionAbout.setIcon(icon2)
        self.actionAbout_Qt = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout_Qt.setObjectName(u"actionAbout_Qt")
        self.actionZoom_In = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionZoom_In.setObjectName(u"actionZoom_In")
        icon3 = QIcon()
        iconThemeName = u"zoom-in"
        if QIcon.hasThemeIcon(iconThemeName):
            icon3 = QIcon.fromTheme(iconThemeName)
        else:
            icon3.addFile(u":/icons/images/zoom-in.svgz", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)

        self.actionZoom_In.setIcon(icon3)
        self.actionZoom_Out = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionZoom_Out.setObjectName(u"actionZoom_Out")
        icon4 = QIcon()
        iconThemeName = u"zoom-out"
        if QIcon.hasThemeIcon(iconThemeName):
            icon4 = QIcon.fromTheme(iconThemeName)
        else:
            icon4.addFile(u":/icons/images/zoom-out.svgz", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)

        self.actionZoom_Out.setIcon(icon4)
        self.actionPrevious_Page = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPrevious_Page.setObjectName(u"actionPrevious_Page")
        icon5 = QIcon()
        iconThemeName = u"go-previous-view-page"
        if QIcon.hasThemeIcon(iconThemeName):
            icon5 = QIcon.fromTheme(iconThemeName)
        else:
            icon5.addFile(u":/icons/images/go-previous-view-page.svgz", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)

        self.actionPrevious_Page.setIcon(icon5)
        self.actionNext_Page = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNext_Page.setObjectName(u"actionNext_Page")
        icon6 = QIcon()
        iconThemeName = u"go-next-view-page"
        if QIcon.hasThemeIcon(iconThemeName):
            icon6 = QIcon.fromTheme(iconThemeName)
        else:
            icon6.addFile(u":/icons/images/go-next-view-page.svgz", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)

        self.actionNext_Page.setIcon(icon6)
        self.actionContinuous = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionContinuous.setObjectName(u"actionContinuous")
        self.actionContinuous.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionBack = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionBack.setObjectName(u"actionBack")
        self.actionBack.setEnabled(False)
        icon7 = QIcon()
        icon7.addFile(u":/icons/images/go-previous-view.svgz", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.actionBack.setIcon(icon7)
        self.actionForward = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionForward.setObjectName(u"actionForward")
        self.actionForward.setEnabled(False)
        icon8 = QIcon()
        icon8.addFile(u":/icons/images/go-next-view.svgz", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.actionForward.setIcon(icon8)
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(u"centralWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.widget = QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.splitter = QSplitter(self.widget)
        self.splitter.setObjectName(u"splitter")
        self.splitter.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        
      
        self.searchView = QListView(self.splitter)

        self.searchView.setObjectName(u"searchView")
   
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.searchView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.searchView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)#
      
  
        self.bookmarkTab = QWidget()
        self.bookmarkTab.setObjectName(u"bookmarkTab")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.bookmarkTab)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        self.bookmarkView = QTreeView(self.bookmarkTab)
        self.bookmarkView.setObjectName(u"bookmarkView")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.bookmarkView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.bookmarkView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.bookmarkView.setHeaderHidden(True)

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.bookmarkView)

     
        self.pagesTab = QWidget()
        self.pagesTab.setObjectName(u"pagesTab")

        self.pdfView = QPdfView(self.splitter)
        self.pdfView.setObjectName(u"pdfView")
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(10)
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.pdfView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pdfView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.pdfView)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.splitter)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(u"menuBar")
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 700, 23))
        self.menuFile = QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName(u"menuFile")
        self.menuHelp = QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName(u"menuHelp")
        self.menuView = QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuView.setObjectName(u"menuView")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(u"mainToolBar")
        self.mainToolBar.setMovable(False)
        self.mainToolBar.setFloatable(False)
        MainWindow.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(u"statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuView.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionQuit)
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionAbout)
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionAbout_Qt)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionZoom_In)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionZoom_Out)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionPrevious_Page)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionNext_Page)
        self.menuView.addSeparator()
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionContinuous)
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.mainToolBar.addSeparator()
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.actionZoom_Out)
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.actionZoom_In)
        self.mainToolBar.addSeparator()
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.actionBack)
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.actionForward)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        # self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)


        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"PDF Viewer", None))
        self.actionOpen.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Open...", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionOpen.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Ctrl+O", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionQuit.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Quit", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionQuit.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Ctrl+Q", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionAbout.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"About", None))
        self.actionAbout_Qt.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"About Qt", None))
        self.actionZoom_In.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Zoom In", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionZoom_In.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Ctrl++", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionZoom_Out.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Zoom Out", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionZoom_Out.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Ctrl+-", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionPrevious_Page.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Previous Page", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionPrevious_Page.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"PgUp", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionNext_Page.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Next Page", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionNext_Page.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"PgDown", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.actionContinuous.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Continuous", None))
        self.actionBack.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Back", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.actionBack.setToolTip(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"back to previous view", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.actionForward.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Forward", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.actionForward.setToolTip(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"forward to next view", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        # self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.bookmarkTab), QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Bookmarks", None))
        # self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.pagesTab), QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Pages", None))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"File", None))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Help", None))
        self.menuView.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"View", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpdfsearchmodel.html) states that the information you need can be accessed via roles.
You can inherit QIdentityProxyModel and build your desired text for the DisplayRole.

```py
class MyProxy(QIdentityProxyModel):
    
    def data(index, role):

        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return f'Page {super().data(index, QPdfSearchModel.Role.Page)}: {super().data(index, role)}'

        return super().data(index, role)
```

Comment: @wald_rabe...unfortunately I can't seem to edit your answer but needed to add a bracket left out (There are only 3) and I had to replace 'QPdfSearchModel.Role.Page' with 256 which I figured out only after looking at the C++ documentation for the class..Otherwise is  spot on.